# Vertical image which is always 1 pixel wide

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to insert an vertical image 1 pixel wide into my webpage but depending on the browser, zoom level or position of other elements on the page the image is often resized to be 2 pixels or just disapears. How can I stop this? Am I doing this wrong?

My html image (green space is just 1 pixel of green.

```
 <IMG class="dividerImage dday3" SRC="/SafeSiteLive/images/safesite_documents/icons/greenspace.gif">
```

My css

```
.dividerImage {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with and without the issue?